# How to write the following script in a single line?

Tags: shell-script, for

```
#Gives a list of servers and their instance
for server instance in `/swb/local/scripts/swdList -p SMARTS -a A5SV_2017.1b -e 1 --type=instance --function=SAM --priority=1  | grep -v sis`
  do
    echo "===== $server - $instance ====="
    #Reason for single line, gotta run this on remote servers
    sudo ssh $server "`/swb/local/scripts/amprov /swb/local/scripts/estools/getProperty -s $sam_instance ICS_Notification Active SourceDomainName 2>/dev/null | grep "Partition-" | grep TRUE | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/NOTIFICATION-Partition_//' | sed 's/_Down//' | sort`; do echo "===== Partition alarm "$alarming_partition" on "$sam_instance" ====="; ampm_instance=`echo $alarming_partition | awk -F\/ '{print $2}'`; for device_in_partition in `/swb/opt/InCharge9/IP/smarts/bin/dmctl -s ${ampm_instance} get Partition:: ${alarming_partition}::ConsistsOf | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '::' | awk -F\: '{print $3}'`; do echo -n $device_in_partition; vzb_qap=`/swb/opt/InCharge9/IP/smarts/bin/dmctl -s ${ampm_instance} get UnitaryComputerSystem::${device_in_partition}::vzb_qap`; echo -n  ",vzb_qap="$vzb_qap; device_alarm=`/swb/local/scripts/amprov /swb/local/scripts/estools/getProperty -s $sam_instance ICS_Notification Active SourceDomainName 2>/dev/null | grep TRUE | grep '_Down' | egrep -v '(Interface|BGP)' | grep $device_in_partition | awk '{print $1}'`; echo -n ",UCS_alarm="$device_alarm; echo; done;"
    echo
  done
```

PS:Thanks a lot for responses guys, my bad, I tried to make it look less complicated by cutting down stuff, but here's what I have written as is.

Comment: What does it do and what is our motivation to make it a single line?  What does `Y= [...]` do other than complain and error?

Comment: [Jesse_b's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553256/116858) is a literal interpretation of the question as stated in the question's title (it is also a correct answer). The conversion to a single line list of commands is mostly mechanical. For a better answer, show the _actual_ script, describe your motivation for wanting to write it on a single line (this is almost _never_ necessary, not even in interactive shells), and, most crucially, explain what issues you've had with doing this yourself.  That last point would allow us to most efficiently help you.

Comment: I'm also noticing that the script makes _exclusive_ use of unquoted variable expansions and command substitutions. The result of the script would therefore depend on the output of your various commands, but also potentially on what filenames you happened to have on files in various directories (unquoted expansions are split on whitespace, and the generated words undergo filename generation).

Comment: As for the errors, I get the following (I tested with both ; and , between the multiple do-statements)

Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
zsh: ====, ampm_instance=, for device_in_partition in ; do echo -n , vzb_qap=, echo -n  ,vzb_qap=, device_alarm=, echo -n ,UCS_alarm=, echo; done; not found

Answer (score 3):

I was able to suppress my urge to cry long enough to liberally apply `;` to your script in order to make it a single line:

```
Y= [...]; for X in `shell command $Y`; do echo "=== "$X" on "$Y" ==="; Z=`echo $X | awk -F\/ '{print $2}'`; for W in `shell command ${Z} awk -F\: '{print $3}'`; do echo -n $W; V=`shell command ${Z} ${W}`; echo -n  ",V="$V; U=`shell command $Y`; echo -n ",T="$U; echo; done; echo; done
```

Also: it won't work, at least because `Y= [...]` is not a valid command but probably other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, depite I totally agree with comments below Your post, to first write the same as short as possible (besides to get used to not use backticks, the one character more generally saves You a lot of trouble for more complex / nested command substitution cases).

```
Y=[...]
for X in $(shell command $Y); do
    echo ===\ $X\ on\ $Y\ ===
    Z=$(echo $X | cut -d/ -f2)
    for W in $(shell command $Z | cut -d: -f3); do 
        echo $W,V=$(shell command $Z $W),T=$(shell command $Y)
    done
    echo
done
```

Then remove all the unneeded identation while replacing needed(=meaningful) line-breaks with semi-colons (+ blank for readability).

```
Y=[...]; for X in $(shell command $Y); do echo ===\ $X\ on\ $Y\ ===; Z=$(echo $X | cut -d/ -f2); for W in $(shell command $Z | cut -d: -f3); do echo $W,V=$(shell command $Z $W),T=$(shell command $Y); done; echo; done
```

If Your goal is to make it as short as possible You can remove all unneeded whitespaces:

```
Y=[...];for X in $(shell command $Y);do echo ===\ $X\ on\ $Y\ ===;Z=$(echo $X|cut -d/ -f2);for W in $(shell command $Z|cut -d: -f3);do echo $W,V=$(shell command $Z $W),T=$(shell command $Y);done;echo;done
```

Or if You want to do it a different way, You can try:

```
Y=[...];shell command $Y|xargs -n1 bash -c "echo ===\\ \$1\\ on\\ $Y\\ ===;Z=\$(echo \$1|cut -d/ -f2);shell command \$Z|cut -d: -f3|xargs -n1 bash -c \"echo \\\$1,V=\\\$(shell command \$Z \\\$1),T=\\\$(shell command $Y)\";echo"
```

or:

```
Y=[...];bash -c "for X in \$*;do echo ===\ \$X\ on\ \$*\ ===;bash -c \"for W in \\\$(shell command \\\$*|cut -d: -f3);do echo \\\$W,V=\\\$(shell command \\\$* \\\$W),T=\\\$(shell command $Y)\";echo\$(echo \$X|cut -d/ -f2)" $(shell command $Y)
```

Also You may want to optimize $(shell command) if it is always same shell command (let away shell and just wrtie command, ot make a var from it before, e.g.:

```
Y=[...];C='shell command';for X in $($C $Y);do echo ===\ $X\ on\ $Y\ ===;Z=$(echo $X|cut -d/ -f2);for W in $($C $Z|cut -d: -f3);do echo $W,V=$($C $Z $W),T=$($C $Y);done;echo;done
```

Or even:

```
Y=[...];C='shell command';E=echo;for X in $($C $Y);do $E ===\ $X\ on\ $Y\ ===;Z=$($E $X|cut -d/ -f2);for W in $($C $Z|cut -d: -f3);do $E $W,V=$($C $Z $W),T=$($C $Y);done;$E;done
```

Especially the last one looks very technical, I think I prefer that as one-line :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use `env_parallel` from GNU Parallel.

Your code is really hard to read and will be hard for others to maintain. It will be easier if it is split into smaller functions that are exported to the remote servers.

```
env_parallel --session
servers() {
  /swb/local/scripts/swdList -p SMARTS -a A5SV_2017.1b -e 1 --type=instance --function=SAM --priority=1 |
    grep -v sis
}
doit() {
  # Run this on every server
}
env_parallel --nonall --slf <(servers) doit
```